# Restricting access loudly to a global variable defined in a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, unnamed-namespace

I have a small problem relating to namespaces, considering the following in a header file:

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        void SetMemberValue(double value) { _member = value; }
        double FunctionThatUsesMember(double a) { return a * _member; }
        double AnotherFuncThatUsesMember(double a) { return a / _member; }
        static double _member = 0.01;
    }
}
```

I did not want the user to be able to change the value of `_member` via `A::B::_member = some_value`. After reading up on unnamed namespaces I changed it to:

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        void SetMemberValue(double value) { _member = value; }
        double FunctionThatUsesMember(double a) { return a * _member; }
        double AnotherFuncThatUsesMember(double a) { return a / _member; }
        namespace {
            double _member = 0.01;
        }
    }
}
```

This forces the user to use the supplied mutator function and works great except for one problem:

If the user continues to use: `A::B::_member = some_value` the code does *not* fail to compile, link, or run; the statement is simply ignored and the default value of `0.01` is used possibly leading to run-time errors or "OMG WTF IS WRONG BBQ!!1!!" moments. (The statement not failing may be an issue with MSVC++ and VS2010 though I am not sure.)

**Question:** Is there a way to have the code fail LOUDLY in some way when `A::B::_member = some_value` is erroneously used?

Comment: If you put an anonymous namespace in the header file, each translation unit will have a `_member` in a different namespace! i.e. `A::B::<anonymous1>::_member`, `A::B::<anonymous2>::_member`.

Comment: You don't want to do that... really... `static` variables (or unnamed namespaces) will create multiple `_member` variables, one per translation unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, note that you get a different version of `_member` in each translation unit! I'm not sure if that is intentional or not.

If you actually want one `_member` in your program and you don't want the user to access a specific global variable, you shouldn't make it visible in the header! Put it into the source and provide functions to access it there:

```
// some-module.h
double getValue();
void   setValue(double value);

// some-module.cpp
#include "some-module.h"
static double value(0.01);
double getValue() { return value; }
void   setValue(double value) { ::value = value; }
```

I left out namespaces because they actually don't matter. You can use an unnamed namespace instead of `static` inside the translation unit but it doesn't make much of a difference, really.

If you claim that the extra function call is unacceptable and everything has to be in the header, you could make value a private member of a class. You'd still need to wrap it into a function to avoid duplicated symbols. If you also wrap the class into an unnamed namespace, you can have one version of the value per translation unit, too:

```
#if ONE_VALUE_PER_TRANSLATION_UNIT
namespace {
#endif

class Value
{
    static double& value() { static double rc(0.01); return rc; }
    friend double getValue();
    friend void   setValue(double value);
};
double getValue() { return Value::value(); }
void   setValue(double value) { Value::value() = value; }

#if ONE_VALUE_PER_TRANSLATION_UNIT
}
#endif
```

Obviously, you can add more function accessing the value in all of these case. I just demonstrated access using simple non-member function `getValue()` and `setValue()`. What you really expose is up to you.

Comment: Having duplicate values in each TU was unintentional. Moving the namespace definition to the `.cpp` file worked and fails to compile loudly with not one but TWO errors: `_member: _is not a member of A::B` (which it isn't! :D) and `_member: undeclared identifier`